# liferay auto deploy not working

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to build the theme in liferay 6.2. I am able to build the theme but auto deploy is not working.
I have set autodeploy directory in portal-setup-wizard.properties like

> auto.deploy.enabled=true
>
> auto.deploy.deploy.dir=${liferay.home}/deploy

the entries in build.user.properties are

> app.server.portal.dir = D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT
> app.server.lib.global.dir = D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\lib\ext
> app.server.deploy.dir = D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps
> app.server.type = tomcat
> app.server.dir = D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42

when build is successful I got message in console as

> Copying 1 file to D:\Projects\Site\bundles\deploy

I am unable to rectify from where it is taking deploy directory path. I didn't specify D:\Projects\Site\bundles\deploy any where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto deploy directory should be set in portal-ext.properties not in portal-setup-wizard.properties.

Also I was missing app.server.parent.dir in build.user.properties file. It should be

> app.server.parent.dir=D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1

Comment: note that portal-setup-wizard.properties works as well, but would be considered unexpected. Also note that this file typically defines liferay.home - if you move your installation to a different location, this value is still unchanged and can lead to unexpected behaviour

Comment: so ideally, where should we write portal configuration in portal-setup-wizard.properties or in portal-ext.properties

Comment: Liferay by defaults set liferay.home in  portal-setup-wizard.properties using which we can set our liferay root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `portal-setup-wizard.properties` has correct liferay home setup. Sometimes, we rename liferay home folder but forgot to update in the `portal-setup-wizard.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

**make sure, portal hot deploy working:**

Find your theme's war file, which is in D:\Projects\Site\bundles\deploy
and copy it to Portal's deploy folder. If it disappears from here, hot deploy working.

**make sure that your login name is *user***

**make sure, that you are using the same version of Plugin SDK as your portal version**

**check plugins SDK's build.properties that it has the appropriate tomcat version**, like:

```
app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-7.0.62
```

**make sure, that your plugin SDK knows, where the portal is**

My login name is *peter*, here is my *build.peter.properties* file, which is in plugin's SDK directory (I use Linux):

```
app.server.parent.dir=/home/peter/apps/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5
```

If you tomcat version is not the same as in the build.properties file,
, but let's say, 7.0.42, put this also into the build.your-login-name.properties file:

```
app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-7.0.42
```

It is enough for the SDK placing built war files into Portal's deploy directory, assuming, that you are just unzipped liferay bundle and not tweaked directories.

Answer (score -1):

`C:\server\profiles\AppSrv01\bin\liferay`

`C:\server\profiles\AppSrv01\liferay`

Rename the `liferay` folder, any one but make sure dont rename which is not being used by server